# Printing Story Map Journals?

Tags: arcgis-online, printing, internet-explorer, story-map

In the Esri blog [Print your Story Map Journal](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2016/10/30/print-your-story-map-journal/) the instructions for doing so start:

> **Step 1**. Open the Story Map Journal.
>
> **Step 2**. Click the share link found in the app header.
>
> **Step** 3. Click Print in the upper right corner.
>
> This will open the Map Journal in print preview mode.

When I try to do this, on a Story Map Journal which I have published, using the steps below, and **Internet Explorer 11**, I get stuck.

1. Open [William & James Slight - Map Engravers & Test Cricketer](https://www.arcgis.com/apps/MapJournal/index.html?appid=163b6d4177354fbb93ba9ed4aedd8ee3) which is a Story Map Journal
2. Click the share link found in the app header (it has tip that says "Get a shot link")

[image]

3. Click Print in the upper right corner.

[image]

This **should** open the Map Journal in print preview mode but what I observe instead is that it opens a web page that says:

> To access the printable version of this Story Maps [sic]: [open the story](https://www.arcgis.com/apps/MapJournal/index.html?appid=163b6d4177354fbb93ba9ed4aedd8ee3) and
>   use the print button located in the share dialog.

I think that is precisely what I did to get the same point so I seem to be stuck in a loop.

Does anyone know how I can print this particular Story Map Journal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the instructions in your question, I can open the story map in print preview without problem, as you can see below:

[image]

However, if I reload (refresh) the webpage, or even copy and paste the link into the browser, I got the same message that you get:

> To access the printable version of this Story Maps: open the story and
>   use the print button located in the share dialog.

May be something blocking your browser to open the print preview. Try to press `Ctrl + mouse left-click` on the `Print` button to open the print preview, and see if that can solve the problem.

Comment: Pressing `Ctrl + mouse left-click` on the `Print` button to open the print preview does not fix it for me but switching from Internet Explorer 11 to Chrome does - thanks for testing!

Comment: I tested on Chrome and FireFox, and it worked without any problem. That's why I did not think it is a browser problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the same procedure as in my question, but using Chrome as my web browser, instead of Internet Explorer 11, then I am able to see the print preview.

If using Chrome, I reload (refresh) the webpage, or copy/paste the link into the browser, then I get the same message that I see at the outset on Internet Explorer.

I think there *may* be something astray still but at least I am no longer stuck when wanting to try and print my Story Map Journal.